# jQuery UI Slider filement group to drag a slider using javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

I want to control jquery UI slider using JavaScript. I want to move slider to certain position when a event is triggered.

```
    $('select#dn_event_date, select#up_event_date').selectToUISlider(

            {
                    // labels and tooltipSrc are selectToUISlider specific options
                    labels: 0                       
                    sliderOptions: {                        
                        // swapped out stop for change here
                    change: function(){
                            // Here i want to control to move slider to certain position                        
                            }
                      }
                }

        );
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you using a plugin?

Comment: Yes i'm using filamant group slider.[click here](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support/)!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use the `value()` function

for example let's say you have button and when the user click it you need to move the slider about 60% from the start:

```
$('#btnRun').click(function(){
    $(".selector").slider("value",60);
});
```

check [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) for more information.